# Jeito certo de fazer o autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Tenho o seguinte `script` *autocomplete*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_cliente").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PreVenda/CarregaClientePorId",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.id,
                            value: item.id,
                            id: item.nome_razao
                        };
                    }))

                }
            })
        }, select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui)
            $("#nome_cliente").val(ui.item.id);
        },
        messages:
    {
        noResults: "", results: ""
    }
    });
})
```

Esse `script`, ao informar o ID do cliente, é carregado uma lista de IDs, e ao selecionar o ID desejado, é preenchido o nome do cliente. Ele está fazendo isso certinho, mas ao selecionar uma vez, eu não consigo clicar para selecionar de novo. Só consigo selecionar de novo se eu apertar nas teclas para baixo ou para cima, e pressionar a tecla ENTER. Eu não consigo selecionar ao clicar com o mouse, e aparece o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Gostaria de saber o que eu estou fazendo de errado no *autocomplete*, para poder conseguir clicar e selecionar mais de uma vez.

Comment: Troca o disparador de ready para click + o input do autocomplete

Comment: amigo, deu certo não

Comment: Teria que postar o HTML na pergunta pra gente tentar reproduzir o problema. Por é esquisito isso. Talvez esteja dando algum conflito com outro código.